# I'm getting disconnected from ble connection status = 22 using bluetooth-nativescript plugin from Eddy Verbruggen

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, nativescript

I have a button with 3 stages cycle, where I can start a fan, boost it, or turn it off, while I'm subscribed to notifications to check its current speed. The issue is when I try to turn on/off the fan, I get this status message:
    MyGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange, status: 22, new state: 0
I lose my ble connection with the device, and can't seem to find a proper solution to reconnect it.
Can you help understanding why is it happening and how can I fix this?
Thanks

```
function startBtn(args) {
    const button = args.object;
    const page = button.page;
    const frame = page.frame;


    if (index === undefined) {
        if(!isNotifyOn){
            isLoaded = true;
            readFan();
            isNotifyOn = true;
        }


        ble.write({
            peripheralUUID: global.peripheral.UUID,
            serviceUUID: 'd8b5a80c-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b',
            characteristicUUID: 'd8b5aa1e-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b',
            value: '0x01'

        }).then((result) => {
            index = "BOOST";
            console.log("LIGA TE!" + result);

        }, function (err) {
            console.log("write error: " + err);
        });
    } else if (index === "BOOST") {

        ble.write({
            peripheralUUID: global.peripheral.UUID,
            serviceUUID: 'd8b5a80c-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b',
            characteristicUUID: 'd8b5aa1e-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b',
            value: '0x01'

        }).then((result) => {
            index = "OFF";
            console.log("BOOST!" + result);

        }, function (err) {
            console.log("write error: " + err);
        });
    } else {
        stopNotify();
        isLoaded = false;
        isNotifyOn = false;
        index = undefined;
        ble.write({
            peripheralUUID: global.peripheral.UUID,
            serviceUUID: 'd8b5a80c-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b',
            characteristicUUID: 'd8b5aa1e-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b',
            value: '0x00'

        }).then((result) => {


            console.log("DESLIGA TE!" + result);

        }, function (err) {
            console.log("write error: " + err);
        });
    }


}

function stopNotify() {

    ble.stopNotifying({
        peripheralUUID: global.peripheral.UUID,
        serviceUUID: 'd8b5ac12-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b',
        characteristicUUID: 'd8b5ae06-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b'
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("STOP@!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("unsubscribe error: " + err);
    });


}

function readFan() {

            ble.startNotifying({
            peripheralUUID: global.peripheral.UUID,
            serviceUUID: 'd8b5ac12-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b',
            characteristicUUID: 'd8b5ae06-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b',
            onNotify: function (result) {
                var data = new Uint8Array(result.value);
                var valuePerMinute = convert(data);
                var valuePerSecond = convertToLS(valuePerMinute);

                source.set("currentValue", valuePerSecond);
                console.log("readFan");
            }
        }).then(function () {

            console.log("subscribed for notifications");


        }, function (err) {
            console.log("notification error: " + err);

        });


}

 bluetooth.connect({
                UUID: peri.UUID,
                onConnected: function (_peripheral) {

                    var navigationEntry2 = {
                        moduleName: "tab-view/tab-view",
                        context: {
                            peripheral: peri
                        },
                        animated: true,
                        transition: {
                            name: "slide",
                            duration: 300,
                            curve: "ease"
                        }
                    };
                    var topmost = frameModule.topmost();
                    topmost.navigate(navigationEntry2);
                },
                onDisconnected: function (_peripheral) {

                    reconnectBle();

                    console.log("Periperhal disconnected with UUID: " + _peripheral.UUID);
                }
            });



        }

    };


function reconnectBle(){
        bluetooth.connect({
            UUID: _peripheral.UUID,
            onConnected: function (_peripheral) {

              console.log("reconnected to "+ _peripheral.UUID);
            },
            onDisconnected: function (_peripheral) {

                reconnectBle();

                console.log("Periperhal disconnected with UUID: " + _peripheral.UUID);
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you connect to the peripheral?

Comment: I edited with the code you asked. It's not in the same page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `setTimeout(reconnectBle, 0)`. Many (all?) BLE callbacks require the ability to complete before another BLE request is made. Here, you are attempting to fire a BLE request in the callback handler for `onDisconnected`. By using a `setTimeout`, the callback thread will be allowed to complete, then the reconnect can start in the appropriate context.

Comment: Should I use on every Ble callback? On notify, should I treat it like that as well? It makes all sense.